# Angular in chrome auto-firing ng-click

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, angularjs-ng-click

I think I'm losing my mind

I'm working on a medium-large angular app.  I came in and rebooted this morning and now angular seems to be executing every ng-click function when the state loads (I'm using $stateProvider).  Was definitely not happening yesterday.

Doesn't happen in canary, or ie, or FF.. Just vanilla chrome (I'm on 43.0.2357.124 m)

If I step out of one of the ng-click calls it dumps me into angular.js:10555

```
functionCall: function(fn, contextGetter) {
    var argsFn = [];
    if (this.peekToken().text !== ')') {
      do {
        argsFn.push(this.expression());
      } while (this.expect(','));
    }
    this.consume(')');

    var parser = this;

    return function(scope, locals) {
      var args = [];
      var context = contextGetter ? contextGetter(scope, locals) : scope;

      for (var i = 0; i < argsFn.length; i++) {
        args.push(argsFn[i](scope, locals));
      }
      var fnPtr = fn(scope, locals, context) || noop;

      ensureSafeObject(context, parser.text);
      ensureSafeObject(fnPtr, parser.text);

      // IE stupidity! (IE doesn't have apply for some native functions)

//vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvRIGHT HEREvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
      var v = fnPtr.apply
            ? fnPtr.apply(context, args)
            : fnPtr(args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3], args[4]);
//^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^RIGHT HERE^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

      return ensureSafeObject(v, parser.text);
    };
  }
```

(Since the problem is in chrome it's hitting fnPtr.apply(context, args) which is running my ng-clicks)

Once it's loaded all the way, everything works as expected.  It's as though when it links my ng-clicks it's executing them!

It's 'running' the ng-clicks in every scope.  Both in the 'master controller' down to directives in whichever state I've loaded (it makes datepickers go absolutely nuts)

Going back and forth between scopes doesn't re-fire the ng-clicks that weren't cleaned up (nav bar buttons for instance).  But any new elements that load are susceptible.

I undid changes far back enough that I'm sure anything weird I did should be gone.

I'm going to poke around another few hours then try to re-create in a minimal example, but I'm hoping it's a chrome-update (although none of my other angular apps are having this problem :/ )

---

My impression is the functionCall method above should be running, and returning a function that'll get called when I actually click, but it's executing it as well as 'linking' it for later executing.

---

Update #1 - I stuck a console.log in the above function to spit out what it was trying to parse out

ok, in canary (and I assume FF and IE): only non-click-y angular-y things get run through the above functionCall function (like

```
<button title="{{'Edit '+myCoolName.replace('_', ')}}"... </button>
```

buut, in chrome: the above AND ng-clicks are getting run through that function.

Loaded: btTypeName.replace('*', ' ')

Loaded: ((!newModel.author) ? "Create New " : ("Edit "+newModel.author+"'s ")) + btTypeName.replace('*', ' ')
Loaded: btTypeName.replace('*', ' ')

Loaded: ((!newModel.author) ? "Create New " : ("Edit "+newModel.author+"'s ")) + btTypeName.replace('*', ' ')
Loaded: openReports();  <---- this shouldn't be here :o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sweet lord I figured it out.

AngularJS Batarang released a new update and it killed everything.  Removed it and everything's good as new (good as old?) anyways...

Looks like version: 0.8.0 released yesterday (6/18/15) is responsible.

I filed an issue in github, https://github.com/angular/angularjs-batarang/issues/227